# What's the Absolute Fastest Way to Fetch External IP Address?

Tags: .net, ip-address

I've seen several methods of retrieving your external IP address in .NET; what I'm wondering is, all of the usual variables being the same (internet connection speed, etc.) what is the **fastest** code for getting your external IP address?

Here's the fastest I've seen so far:

```
Private Function GetExternalIP() As String

Dim m As Match = Match.Empty

Try

    Dim wClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim strURL As String = wClient.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip")
    Dim strPattern As String = "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b"

    ' Look for the IP
     m = Regex.Match(strURL, strPattern)

Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("GetExternalIP Error: {0}", ex.Message))
End Try

' Failed getting the IP
If m.Success = False Then Return "IP: N/A"

' Got the IP
Return m.value

End Function
```

I know there are other ways to get the external IP as well, i.e. using the `WebBrowser` control to fetch a page that reports your IP, and then parsing it out of the results, or even some command-line methods, such as fiddling with:

`nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com`

Has anyone ever taken the time to run their own tests to get the **fastest** method?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give an absolute answer to any question that asks about a 'fastest way'. Moreover, in this context, the problem is not only on the code used but also in the latency of the network and on how many attempts are executed in a finite time. Some servers could stop responding if they see a lot of requests of this kind coming from the same address. (DoS attacks comes to minf)

However, a little improvement on you code could be to try with a different service that return a bare-bone information about the ip and not a lot of other unrelated informations

```
Dim wbc = New WebClient()
Dim externalIP = wbc.DownloadString("http://www.realip.info/api/p/realip.php")
externalIP = (New Regex("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")).
              Matches(externalIP)(0).ToString()
```

Running this code for 100 times gives me 28 elapsed seconds  while your attempt against google gives me 34 seconds. But as I have said, you need to test from your location.

**EDIT:**
Using http://checkip.amazonaws.com and we can totally bypass the regex parser and using instead the IPAddress class. Now the loop (100 times) seems more speedy (again, I think it is largely dependant on the response time of the server)

```
Dim externalIP = wbc.DownloadString("http://checkip.amazonaws.com")
Dim ip = New IPAddress(externalIP.Split("."c).Select(Function(x) Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray)
```

Comment: Interesting. I was using Google as the source since it's probably more likely to 'always be there' in the future, rather than a site that could disappear at any time. I've seen so many IP sites that just go away, breaking your app. But I do understand the concept of getting the info from a page that doesn't include a bunch of other source code to parse through.

Comment: I agree with your concerns about availability of the service. I keep that url in a config file for easy maintenance/change

Comment: If only Google would provide us a simple IP info page. =)

Comment: As another test, I just whipped up a function to get a page w/only the IP (http://checkip.amazonaws.com), & using webRequest/WebResponse/StreamReader, and ran the 2 functions 1 after the other. The code above (1), parsing the entire Google page was slightly faster than the page that only has the IP (2). Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/n6okkNZ.png

Comment: Second function used was:
`Public Function GetExternalIP2() As String

        Dim wrReq As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/")
        Dim wrRep As Net.WebResponse = wrReq.GetResponse()
        Dim srStream As New IO.StreamReader(wrRep.GetResponseStream)

        Dim strResult As String = srStream.ReadLine()

        srStream.Close()

        Return strResult

End Function`

Comment: But what if you just use DownloadString and parse the IP?